# How would I show that if $S,T\subset M$ and $S\subset T$ then $cl(S)\subset cl(T)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I cant really think of anything to say other then to say that since $S\subset T$ then that's basically why cl$(S)$$\subset$ cl$(T)$. But that just seems too easy and it's probably not right. So I thought, maybe I should show that all of $S$'s limit points are in $T$'s closure. But that's not really much different than saying that since $S$ is a subset of $T$ then cl$(S)$$\subset$ cl$(T)$. What about if I showed that each point in $S$ has a limit in $T$. Would that work?

Comment: Are they subsets of an arbitrary topological space? How do you define the closure of a set?

Comment: If you define it as the intersection of all closed supersets, then it isn't difficult either. For the closure of $S$ you are intersecting over all closed subsets containing $S$, among which are all closed subsets containing $T$. So cl($S$) $\subseteq$ cl($T$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: If $x$ is a limit point of $S$, then every open nbhd of $x$ contains a point of $S$; and if moreover $S\subseteq T$, then every open nbhd of $x$ contains ... what?

Comment: a point of $T$... Right?

Comment: @Kyle: That’s right $-$ and that makes $x$ a limit point of $T$, just as you wanted.

Comment: @Brian becarefull, you should mention to look at the cases $S=\varnothing$

Comment: @Dominic: Not a problem: if $S$ has no limit point, then vacuously every limit point of $S$ is a limit point of $T$.

Comment: oh right sry did made a mistake

Comment: Ah thank you, I wasn't sure how to go about wording the problem.

Comment: @Kyle: You’re welcome. One way to think about how to write it up is what Dominic suggests in his answer: start with your definition of *closure* and see exactly what it takes to make $\operatorname{cl}S\subseteq\operatorname{cl}T$ true. Most proofs at this level are actually fairly straightforward if you just untangle the definitions to see what’s needed and what you have from the hypotheses.

Comment: I'm actually starting to see that almost any proof in analysis at this level is almost literally untangeling definitions and combining them with other definitions... Oh, but for the love of math, I'll do it over and over again.

Comment: Actually I just remembered, so then would the same idea apply to if I had to show that int$(S)$$\subset$int$(T)$?

Comment: @Kyle: Yes: if $x$ has an open nbhd contained within $S$, then ...

Answer (score 2):

Take the definition of the closing, for example taking the definition that the closing of $S$ is the intersection of all closed sets $N$ such that $S\subset N$. I don't know which one you are using, but beginning with the definition is a good start.

Or you can take the definition $\operatorname{cl}(S)= S \cup \partial S$. If $x\in \partial S$ there are 2 cases. The first one is $x\in S$, than $x\in T$ because $S\subset T$. The other case is, that $x$ is a limit point of $S$. For this case looks as Brians answer.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I'll definitely use it!